# What's the way to add values to helm deployments in Argo?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, helm

I want to deploy apps via ArgoCD with Helm and use the provided Helm charts. I also want to specify custom values but in a declarative way (not setting them after deployment with Argo gui or cli). Argo seems to assume that you control the Helm Repo and therefore the `values.yaml`, but I'd like to use the repos out there and not mirror everything while having the `values.yaml` in git repo. How is this usually done?

1. Mirror helm chart with own `values.yaml` (a lot of work to keep up to date with 15+ apps)
2. Have an app in a git repo that uses helm (not sure how to do this)
3. Have a helm repo and an app that kustomizes it (also not sure how to do this)

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does the ArgoCD UI provide something equivalent to flux HelmRelease objects?

Comment: I don't know flux, so I can't answer that. My current workaround is to create a helm chart that references the original helm chart.